# How do I share my music that is already on a Buffalo NAS drive with itunes?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, nas

Hi I have spent a great deal of time copying my own CD's to a Buffalo NAS drive using Windows Media Player. Because my wife and daughter have ipods I need to share that music within itunes but am confused as to how.
Most of the files are in WAV format and I do not want move them from their current location on the NAS drive because of the space they take up.
When I hold down Ctrl and click itunes it asked me to create a new library or choose an existing one. I already have an existing library on my NAS drive so I choose that option but nothing happens except an itunes folder appearing in the shared Music folder on my NAS. Is this what it is supposed to do and I am being impatient or have I done something wrong.

Ongoing I plan to continue to use Windows Media Player to copy my CD's to the NAS drive but want itunes to still see all the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move music that is shared via iTunes onto an iPod. Since the music is already on a NAS, I'd mount the NAS on all 3 computer, and add the music into iTunes directly on each machine. (just make sure itunes is not sorting the music folder).